# Local date string in format yyyy/mm/dd is replacing mm with dd in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, format

So i have this string im my json:
"2019-05-24T14:43:39.89"

And this is my function for displaying this date

```
function getDateAndTime(dateString){
        function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
        }
    let date = new Date(dateString);
    return addZero(date.getDay())+'/'+addZero(date.getMonth())+'/'+addZero(date.getFullYear())+ ' ' +addZero(date.getHours())+':'+addZero(date.getMinutes());
}
```

The problme is that the output is 
05/04/2019 14:43

Its replacing month and days in new Date method and converts 24 to 4 i dont know why.

Is it any way to convert utc date string in format yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy date object? In javascript?

Comment: Date objects don't have a format, they're just a number (milliseconds since the epoch) and some methods.

Comment: So is any way to convert miliseconds to date object  taking into consideration time zone?

Comment: Because when i convert miliseconds to date using new Date() it creates me incorrect date.

Comment: `new Date(milliseconds)`, make sure the value is type Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *getDay* method returns the day of the week, not the day of the month. May 24 was a Friday, so *getDay* returns 5. You should use *getDate*, which returns 24.

Months are zero indexed, *getMonth* for May returns 4 not 5. So `addZero(date.getMonth())` should be `addZero(date.getMonth() + 1)`.